# Creating check box that is directly clickable in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm quite new to javascript and I'm using [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) to create dynamic and interactive tables. It works wonderfully, I just have a little formatting problem.

One of the columns in my data is boolean and I'm using the [tickCross](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/format#format-builtin) formatter.

I would like to format the column so that the tickbox doesn't disappear and i directly clickable, without clicking inside the cell, like the first column of [this example](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-add-a-checkbox-column/).

I tried to look for the setting in the documentation and in the code, but I cant't find the what I'm looking for.

Thank in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add a `cellClick` option to the column, so that when you click the cell it is immediately updated.
Here is a working example, https://jsfiddle.net/s60qL1hw/1/.

This sets the cell value to the opposite of the current value.  It should be improved on to handle undefined values, null values, etc. how you would want to handle those.  However, it should work for most cases.

```
    cellClick: function(ev, cell){
      cell.setValue(!cell.getValue());
    }
```

The `cellClick` is for the entire cell.  So if you don't click the tick, but you click whitespace next to it, it is still triggered.  You can use the event target to check if the tick was clicked or not.